# GDI+/WinForms Status overflow when rendering [F#]

Tags: winforms, compiler-errors, f#, overflow, gdi+

This is my first time working with winforms on a large scale of data; and I have about half a year worth of experience. I can't figure out how to sort out this overFlow error, as it seems to be OS-specific, some of my fellow students on mac and Ubuntu can compile it just fine, with an instant picture - but I just get a short glimpse of what looks like [its animated](https://gyazo.com/066d635503793a8e8f1b22f3807db538) (Not supposed to). 
I suspect its because that Windows 10 (my stationary OS) registers that a program is demanding too much cpu?

Anyways heres the object that drawing winforms.

```
 type Animation (listpos , listpos1, listpos2, listpos3,listpos4 , listpos5, listpos6, listpos7, listpos8, listpos9) = class
  let title = "Solarsystem"
  let backColor = Image.FromFile("Star_background.png")
  let size = (800, 600)
  let mutable positions = List.append listpos9 (List.append listpos8 (List.append listpos7 (List.append listpos6 (List.append listpos5 (List.append listpos4 (List.append listpos3 (List.append listpos2 (List.append listpos1 listpos))))))))
  let createForm backColor (width, height) title draw =
    let win = new Form ()
    win.Text <- title
    win.BackgroundImage <- backColor
    win.ClientSize <- Size (width, height)
    win.Paint.Add draw
    win
  let drawPlanet (e : PaintEventArgs) =
    let drawPixel (elm : Position) =
      match elm with
      | {Position.x=x;Position.y=y;} ->
        let rect = new Rectangle (int(x) + 400, int(y) + 200, 10, 10)
        let aBrush : SolidBrush = new SolidBrush (Color.OrangeRed)
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse (aBrush, int(x), int(y), 2 ,2)
    List.map drawPixel positions |> ignore

  let AU2Pixel (AU:float ) =
    (float (fst size) / (2.0*33.0)) * AU + (float(fst size) / 2.0)
  member this.create () =
    let win = createForm backColor size title drawPlanet
    positions <-  positions |> List.map (fun {Position.x=x;Position.y=y;Position.z=z} -> {Position.x=AU2Pixel(x); Position.y=AU2Pixel(y);Position.z=AU2Pixel(z)})
    Application.EnableVisualStyles()
    Application.Run (win)
end
;;
```

And the compiler error-log:

> Se slutningen af denne meddelelse, hvis du vil have detaljer om,
>   hvordan du starter JIT-fejlfinding i stedet for denne dialogboks.
>
> ************** Undtagelsestekst ************** System.OverflowException: Overløbsfejl.    ved
>   System.Drawing.Graphics.CheckErrorStatus(Int32 status)    ved
>   System.Drawing.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brush brush, Int32 x, Int32 y,
>   Int32 width, Int32 height)    ved
>   Testc2c3.drawPixel@134.Invoke(Position elm)    ved
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.List.mapToFreshConsTail[a,b](FSharpList`1
>   cons, FSharpFunc`2 f, FSharpList`1 x)    ved
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.List.map[T,TResult](FSharpFunc`2
>   mapping, FSharpList`1 x)    ved Testc2c3.win@144.Invoke(PaintEventArgs
>   e)    ved
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.h@788.Invoke(Object
>   _arg1, TArgs args)    ved System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)    ved
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)    ved
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e,
>   Int16 layer)    ved System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
>   ved System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    ved
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)    ved
>   System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg,
>   IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>
> ************** Indlæste assemblies ************** mscorlib
>       Assemblyversion: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32-version: 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- testc2c3
>       Assemblyversion: 0.0.0.0
>       Win32-version: 
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Bjarke/OneDrive/Datalogi/PoP/Projekter/11gPoP/testc2c3.exe
>   ---------------------------------------- FSharp.Core
>       Assemblyversion: 4.4.0.0
>       Win32-version: 4.40.23020.0
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/FSharp.Core/v4.0_4.4.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/FSharp.Core.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Core
>       Assemblyversion: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32-version: 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System
>       Assemblyversion: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32-version: 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Windows.Forms
>       Assemblyversion: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32-version: 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Drawing
>       Assemblyversion: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32-version: 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Drawing.resources
>       Assemblyversion: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32-version: 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_da_b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.resources.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Windows.Forms.resources
>       Assemblyversion: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32-version: 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_da_b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.resources.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- mscorlib.resources
>       Assemblyversion: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32-version: 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>
> ### CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/mscorlib.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_da_b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.resources.dll
>
> ************** JIT-fejlfinding ************** Hvis du vil aktivere JIT-fejlfinding, skal værdien jitDebugging indstilles i afsnittet
>   system.windows.forms i konfigurationsfilen for programmet eller
>   computeren. Programmet skal desuden kompileres med fejlfinding
>   aktiveret.
>
> Eksempel:
>
> Når JIT-fejlfinding er aktiveret, bliver alle ikke-afviklede
>   undtagelser sendt til den JIT-fejlfindingsfunktion, der er registreret
>   på computeren, i stedet for at blive afviklet af denne dialogboks.

Comment: It seems like x and/or y, here; "e.Graphics.FillEllipse (aBrush, int(x), int(y), 2 ,2)" is set to huge value(s). Try to check for that. Also "let aBrush : SolidBrush = new SolidBrush (Color.OrangeRed)" is problematic, since you're not disposing it. Your could just use "Brushes.OrangeRed" instead to rectify.